# Why is this not the correct way to treat this exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

This is probably a silly question but why is the following not true:

$x^\frac{-2}{3}=x^{-1.\tfrac{2}{3}}=x^{-1}x^{\tfrac{2}{3}}=\tfrac{1}{x}.x^{\tfrac{2}{3}}=\tfrac{(x^2)^{1/3}}{x}$

Comment: $x^{-1}x^{2/3} = x^{-1 + \frac{2}{3}}$.

Comment: The meaning of $x^{-2/3}$ isn't entirely clear without knowing what $x$ represents.  In any case you seem to have made some mistakes in arithmetic or in applying laws of exponents.  Check your work by setting (for example) $x=8$ so that the expressions have pretty clear interpretations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is a positive real number, then
\begin{align*}
x^{a + b} & = x^ax^b\\
(x^a)^b & = x^{ab}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the step
$$x^{-1 \cdot \frac{2}{3}} = x^{-1}x^{2/3}$$
is false.
$$x^{-2/3} = x^{-1 \cdot \frac{2}{3}} = \left(x^{2/3}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{x^{2/3}}$$
while
$$x^{-1}x^{2/3} = x^{-1 + \frac{2}{3}} = x^{-1/3} = \left(x^{1/3}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}$$